# How to update Cover Photo to any registered facebook app user using Facebook PHP API?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to add Facebook Cover Photo to the user profile using PHP API.

I tried, but I can only upload the image to user album or photos section. I cant able to update the my app register user cover photo.

How could I do this. Help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not possible directly via Graph API

Comment: then, how could I do using facebook application. Because, I am trying facebook application for setting cover photo from application.